# Unexpected Output in Vaex Function

Tags: python, vaex

I have the following Vaex function I am trying to make:

```
@vaex.register_function(on_expression=True)
def getSumStatsByGroup(df, group, x):
    data = (df.groupby(by=group, agg={'Min' : vaex.agg.min(df[x]), 'Mean' : vaex.agg.mean(df[x]), 'Max' : vaex.agg.max(df[x]),
                              'Variance' : vaex.agg.var(df[x])}))
    return data
```

Although every time I run it I get really messy data resembling this:

```
 File <unknown>:2
    0           AR              2020-12-06 00:00:00.000000000  AR              Argentina       AR                    ARG                   0                    2176.0           150.0           1489103.0               43125.0                3699476.0            nan                       nan                              nan                             nan                                    nan                               nan                                      44938712.0    19523766.0         20593330.0           3599141.0           41339571.0          16.515                0.825
```

Although, when I manually fill in the parameters :

```
df.groupby(by='country_name', agg={'Min' : vaex.agg.min(df['new_confirmed']), 'Mean' : vaex.agg.mean(df['new_confirmed']), 'Max' : vaex.agg.max(df['new_confirmed']),
                              'Variance' : vaex.agg.var(df['new_confirmed'])})
```

The output is as expected. I have tried converting the return value to a pandas dataframe, calling print() on it, changing it to on_expression=False, getting rid of the return keyword in the function, but each time I get the exact same result. I am running this on jupyter notebook and very confused why it works when manually filling in parameters but not with the Vaex function. Any help or explanation is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how the `@register_function` decorator works and its intended use.

The decorator applies the function per row on the dataframe. The expected arguments are one or more columns/expressions, or constants. The function will then take one row of data, and evaluate it and return the result. The function should return a single value (a sample, int, string, perhaps even a list, or a numpy array, I think some of those structures are supported by vaex). Basically the output should be a vaex expression (and groupby does not fit that because the output of that is a dataframe).

This is useful because vaex will run this out-of-core, and in parallel, so you get some speedup. In some way it is similar to `apply`, but the idea is that for a particular project you can build your own in-house extensions to fit exactly your needs.

I hope my explanation makes sense a bit. I think `@register_functiion` should be better documented on the vaex. In any case, here is a [link to the docs](https://vaex.io/docs/tutorial.html#Adding-functions).

Perhaps for your usecase (if I understood it correctly) you might want to take a look at the custom [dataframe accessor stuff](https://vaex.io/docs/tutorial.html#Adding-DataFrame-accessors)